# Git remotes sync between Macs

Tags: git, github

I got a new Mac and now I want to transfer all remotes from older Mac to new Mac in order to avoid manually adding new remotes for about thirty local repositories. Is there a way I can sync or transfer that info?

Comment: If you transfer the entire content of the file system, the remotes will be included.

Comment: "Remotes"? Do you mean "repositories"?

Comment: If you have repositories with linked remotes, then moving the repositories doesn't affect the link. If *others* are using *your* repositories as remotes, then as long as your new Mac is reached using the same URL as the old one, moving the repositories won't affect the link.

Answer (score 1):

Git (as with anything on a computer) is just file based, and nicely stores everything it needs for a repo in a `.git` folder in the root of the repo, copy the whole folder that makes up the repo and it will get you everything you need.

Though I would argue that it would just be easier to clone all the same repos rather than trying to copy them over, keeps your filesystem a little cleaner.